# Highcharter package not found - highchart function not available

Tags: r, highcharts

I want to use the `highcharter` package to chart some stocks. However, I receive some error messages, when I use install.packages and library. When I then try to use the `highchart` function, I get the following error message:

> Error in highchart(type = "stock") : could not find function "highchart".

These are the errors while loading the package:

```
install.packages("highcharter")
```

> trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.4/highcharter_0.7.0.tgz'
>
> Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2851784 bytes (2.7 MB)
>
> ==================================================
>
> downloaded 2.7 MB
>
> tar: Failed to set default locale
>
> The downloaded binary packages are in
>       /var/folders/g7/zltv5nrj1qj0hcmdyql94s3r0000gn/T//RtmpnlCQEr/downloaded_packages

```
library(highcharter)
```

> Error: package or namespace load failed for 'highcharter' in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
>    there is no package called 'data.table'
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   package 'highcharter' was built under R version 3.4.4

Also, when I manually "activate" the package, it will not work either.
Tried to install the package and select it, also tried:

```
remove.packages(c("highcharter", "data.table"))
install.packages('highcharter', dependencies = TRUE)
install.packages('data.table', dependencies = TRUE)
```

Also tried

```
highcharter::highchart
```

This is the code I am running now:

```
# Charting stock prices
hchart(type = "stock") %>% 
  hc_title(text = "monthly log returns") %>% 
  hc_add_series(asset_returns_xts[, symbols[1]], name = symbols[1])
```

I have expected a chart as described with the highcharter documentation, instead the package and function is not found.

Comment: Are you sure `data.table` installs successfully?

Comment: The error message is common when you have another R session open in Windows and attempt to install a loaded package. Can you try shutting all R sessions, opening a new session, and proceed from `install.packages("data.table")` and then `install.packages("highcharter")`?

Answer (score 1):

thank you for your help!
I needed to uninstall R and RStudio from my machine and then it worked.

I am not entirely sure, why but it solved my issue, everything is running smoothly now.

Thank you again!

Best regards,

Bodo