# Failing to install the package "highcharter"

Tags: r, r-highcharter

**When I run these two lines**

```
install.packages(highcharter)
library(highcharter)
```

**I get this error**

```
package �highcharter� was built under R version 3.6.3Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘highcharter’ in readRDS(ffile):
 unknown input format
```

How to fix it?

Comment: May [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56094637/highcharter-package-not-found-highchart-function-not-available) answers you question? Here is another [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31935516/installing-r-packages-error-in-readrdsfile-error-reading-from-connection)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [readRDS(file) in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473831/readrdsfile-in-r)